# Copy object with results of getters

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I have an object that contains a getter.

```
myObject {
    id: "MyId",
    get title () { return myRepository.title; }
}

myRepository.title = "MyTitle";
```

I want to obtain an object like:

```
myResult = {
    id: "MyId", 
    title: "MyTitle"
}
```

I don't want to copy the getter, so:

```
myResult.title;                       // Returns "MyTitle"
myRepository.title = "Another title";
myResult.title;                       // Should still return "MyTitle"
```

I've try:

- $.extend(): But it doesn't iterate over getters. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6145
- Iterating properties as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties), but it doesn't iterate over getters.
- As I'm using angular, using Angular.forEach, as suggested [here](http://blog.shinetech.com/2014/03/07/rich-object-models-and-angular-js-getter-methods/). But I only get properties and not getters.

Any idea? Thx!

**Update**
I was setting the getter using Object.defineProperty as:

```
 "title": { get: function () { return myRepository.title; }},
```

As can be read in the doc:

> **enumerable** true if and only if this property shows up during
>   enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object. Defaults to
>   false.

Setting enumerable: true fix the problem.

```
"title": { get: function () { return myRepository.title; }, enumerable: true },
```

Comment: Sorry, but your object is a syntax error. You need to remove `:function` after a `get` keyword; and you cannot have a normal `title` property and a getter with the same name.

Comment: `$.extend` does work very well. The bug description says "*jQuery.extend copies property getter return values, not their code.*" - however, that's just what you want. Doing it manually with `for in` will do the same.

Comment: Sorry @Bergi, the object sintax is just a copy of the console.log for the object. I'm going to update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>`$.extend` does exactly what you want.</s> (**Update**: You've since said you want non-enumerable properties as well, so it *doesn't* do what you want; see the second part of this answer below, but I'll leave the first bit for others.) The bug isn't saying that the resulting object won't have a `title` property, it's saying that the resulting object's `title` property won't be a *getter*, which is perfect for what you said you wanted.

Example with correct getter syntax:

```js
// The myRepository object
const myRepository = { title: "MyTitle" };

// The object with a getter
const myObject = {
    id: "MyId",
    get title() { return myRepository.title; }
};

// The copy with a plain property
const copy = $.extend({}, myObject);

// View the copy (although actually, the result would look
// the same either way)
console.log(JSON.stringify(copy));

// Prove that the copy's `title` really is just a plain property:
console.log("Before: copy.title = " + copy.title);
copy.title = "foo";
console.log("After:  copy.title = " + copy.title);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Syntax fixes:

- Added missing variable declarations, `=`, and `;`
- Removed duplicate property `title`
- Corrected the getter declaration syntax

---

If you want to include non-enumerable properties, you'll need to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` because they won't show up in a `for-in` loop, `Object.keys`, or `$.extend` (whether or not they're "getter" or normal properties):

```js
// The myRepository object
const myRepository = { title: "MyTitle" };

// The object with a getter
const myObject = {
    id: "MyId",
};
Object.defineProperty(myObject, "title", {
    enumerable: false, // it's the default, this is just for emphasis,
    get: function () {
        return myRepository.title;
    },
});

console.log("$.extend won't visit non-enumerable properties, so we only get id here:");
console.log(JSON.stringify($.extend({}, myObject)));

// Copy it
const copy = {};
for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject)) {
    copy[name] = myObject[name];
}

// View the copy (although actually, the result would look
// the same either way)
console.log("Our copy operation with Object.getOwnPropertyNames does, though:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(copy));

// Prove that the copy's `title` really is just a plain property:
console.log("Before: copy.title = " + copy.title);
copy.title = "foo";
console.log("After:  copy.title = " + copy.title);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thx! I've update the question. The problem was that $.extend doesn't work with getters if  property.enumerable = false;

Comment: @MarioLevrero: True, they also won't show up in a `for-in` loop like Scimonter's. If you want to know about non-enumerable properties, you'll want to use [`Object.getownPropertyNames`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.4).

Comment: @MarioLevrero: I've updated the answer to show how to use `getOwnPropertyNames` (well, one of the ways).

Comment: Yes, thanks for your updated. I didn't notice the false by default enumerable property.

Comment: @MarioLevrero: I was surprised by that too, when I first learned about `defineProperty`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, fix your syntax, though it probably is good in your actual code:

```
myObject = {
    id: "MyId",
    get title () { return myRepository.title; }
}
```

Now, to the answer. :)

You can just use a `for..in` loop to get all the properties, then save them as-is:

```
var newObj = {};
for (var i in myObject) {
    newObj[i] = myObject[i];
}
```

No jQuery, Angular, any other plugins needed!

Comment: Thx! I've update the question. The problem was that for(...) doesn't work with getters if  property.enumerable = false;

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but in **TypeScript** and the method mentioned by T.J. Crowder didnt work.

What did work was the following:

**TypeScript**:

```
function copyObjectIncludingGettersResult(originalObj: any) {

    //get the properties
    let copyObj = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(originalObj).reduce(function (result: any, name: any) {
        result[name] = (originalObj as any)[name];
        return result;
    }, {});

    //get the getters values
    let prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(originalObj);
    copyObj = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype).reduce(function (result: any, name: any) {
        //ignore functions which are not getters
        let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, name);
        if (descriptor?.writable == null) {
            result[name] = (originalObj as any)[name];
        }
        return result;
    }, copyObj);

    return copyObj;
}
```

**Javascript version:**

```
function copyObjectIncludingGettersResult(originalObj) {
  
    //get the properties
    let copyObj = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(originalObj).reduce(function (result, name) {
       
         result[name] = originalObj[name];
        
        return result;
    }, {});

    //get the getters values
    let prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(originalObj);
     copyObj = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype).reduce(function (result,name) {
let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, name);
        if (descriptor?.writable == null) {
            result[name] = originalObj[name];
        }
        return result;
    }, copyObj);
       
    return copyObj;
}
```